# Vim Taglist can not display page function

Tags: vim, ctags, taglist

I 'd like to use Ctag and TagList plugin in my Vim editor, everything works fine except taglist navigation ,it couldn'd display all page functions included but the page defined itself.
and I press ctrl+] it also works well .

eg

```
$var = get_input();recent();function recent(){return true}
```

get_input was defined in another file.Here I can see only "recent" in the TagList sidebar

How to let the sidebar show all functions in my recent working file ?
Thanks for all help

Comment: In my global vimrc file it was added like this let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='/usr/bin/ctags'

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't. Taglist shows you only where things are declared not where you call them. You could search for the filenames inside the directory or use another tool like cflow to see what functions are called from the file.

You can't display that information because ctags doesn't care about. Ctags is a tool to map the **definitions** of functions, defines, etc. Taglist is just showing you information from the tags file that ctags creates. Whatever functions you actually call in your files id none of ctags's concern so you can't display this information with ctags and TagList.